# creating heatmap with R with eye-tracker data

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a table composed by the following data

```
frame,X,Y
```

which is the resulting data from several eye tracking analysis. 
Now I would like to create a Heatmap using R, like the following 
[image]

I tried several script found online, none of them gave me that result.

How can I do?

---

Here some sample data
Ignore the first two columns

```
task,visualization,frame,X,Y
1,b,1,383,221
1,b,1,632,356
1,b,1,947,663
1,b,1,546,206
1,b,1,488,272    
1,b,1,578,752
1,b,1,415,261
1,b,1,693,158
1,b,1,684,528
1,b,1,592,67
1,b,1,393,180
1,b,1,1033,709
1,b,1,1080,739
1,b,1,711,523
1,b,1,1246,49
1,b,1,742,69
1,b,1,601,370
1,b,10,902,684
1,b,10,517,241
1,b,10,583,86
1,b,10,582,754
1,b,10,426,257
1,b,10,575,229
1,b,10,697,150
1,b,10,379,520
1,b,10,390,286
1,b,10,618,396
1,b,10,710,143
1,b,10,383,188
1,b,10,1026,713
1,b,10,1078,625
1,b,10,713,521
```

Comment: Please make your situation reproducible, i.e. provide us with the data and the code needed to mimic your situation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more tips on how to do this.

Comment: You somehow need to "georeference" your image, and it's "simple" kerneling from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this type of plot quite easily using `stat_bin2d` from `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + stat_bin2d(bins = 10)
```

[image]

This does simple binning, as @RomanLustrik suggested you could also perform some kind of kernel smoothing. This can also be done using `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + 
 stat_density2d(geom = "tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE) + 
 geom_point()
```

[image]
Note that `dat` is the example data you gave, geting your data into a `data.frame`:

```
dat = read.table(textConnection("task,visualization,frame,X,Y
    1,b,1,383,221
    1,b,1,632,356
    1,b,1,947,663
    1,b,1,546,206
    1,b,1,488,272    
    1,b,1,578,752
    1,b,1,415,261
    1,b,1,693,158
    1,b,1,684,528
    1,b,1,592,67
    1,b,1,393,180
    1,b,1,1033,709
    1,b,1,1080,739
    1,b,1,711,523
    1,b,1,1246,49
    1,b,1,742,69
    1,b,1,601,370
    1,b,10,902,684
    1,b,10,517,241
    1,b,10,583,86
    1,b,10,582,754
    1,b,10,426,257
    1,b,10,575,229
    1,b,10,697,150
    1,b,10,379,520
    1,b,10,390,286
    1,b,10,618,396
    1,b,10,710,143
    1,b,10,383,188
    1,b,10,1026,713
    1,b,10,1078,625
    1,b,10,713,521"), header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: The 1st solution can be slightly improved by including the image, as such (will require ggpubr):

ggplot(dt, aes(x = world_gazeX, y = world_gazeY)) + background_image(bgimg) + stat_bin2d(bins = 30)